# Split in non-overlapping sub-lists with elements within an interval from the first member

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to split a large ordered list into consecutive non-overlapping sub-lists, such that all elements are within an interval from the first member of the sub-list . For example:

```
list={{1,x},{2,x},{3,x},{4,x},{5,x},{8,x},{13,x},{16,x},{17,x}}
```

And I want to split it so that all first elements are within an interval of 3. The desired result is this:

```
result={{{1,x},{2,x},{3,x}},{{4,x},{5,x}},{{8,x}},{{13,x}},{{16,x},{17,x}}}
```

Notice that the interval is relative to the first member of the sub-list and the final result is non-overlapping. So, for example, {{2,x},{3,x},{4,x}} is not in the result.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26)

Comment: Have you tried playing with `Partition`i.e. `Partition[list, 3]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But yes, I have. The partitioning that I need is not equally spaced and I need this to work with real number values and real-number intervals. The 1,2,3 here is just for illustration.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way using `SplitBy`:

```
split[l:{__}, m_] :=
  Module[{e = l[[1, 1]] + m}
  , SplitBy[l, If[#[[1]] < e, e, e = #[[1]] + m]&]
  ]

split[list, 3]

(* {{{1,x},{2,x},{3,x}},{{4,x},{5,x}},{{8,x}},{{13,x}},{{16,x},{17,x}}} *)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Three variations on WReach's key idea:

```
ClearAll[splitA]
splitA[l : {__}, m_] := Module[{e = l[[1, 1]] + m},
 Last @ Reap @ Scan[Sow[#, If[#[[1]] < e, e,  e = #[[1]] + m]] &, l]]

splitA[list, 3]
```

> ```
>  {{{1, x}, {2, x}, {3, x}}, 
>   {{4, x}, {5, x}}, 
>   {{8, x}}, 
>   {{13, x}}, 
>   {{16, x}, {17, x}}}
> ```

```
ClearAll[splitB]
splitB[l : {__}, m_] := Module[{e = l[[1, 1]] + m},
  Split[l, Or[#2[[1]] < e, e = #2[[1]] + m] &]]

ClearAll[splitC]
splitC[l : {__}, m_] := Module[{e = l[[1, 1]] + m},
  SplitBy[l, Or[#[[1]] < e, e = #[[1]] + m] &]]

splitA[list, 3] == splitB[list, 3] == splitC[list, 3]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
res = 
  Catenate @ Map[Partition[#, UpTo @ 3] &] @ 
    Split[list, #2[[1]] - #1[[1]] == 1 &];

res == result
```

(* True *)

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1, x}, {2, x}, {3, x}, {4, x}, {5, x}, {8, x}, {13, x}, {16, x}, {17, x}};
```

---

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
ConsecutiveQ = Most[#] == Rest[#] - 1 &;

p = Map[Splice@Partition[#, UpTo@3] &];

res = p@SequenceCases[list, x : {__} /; ConsecutiveQ@x[[All, 1]]]

res === result

(*True*)
```